# How to Redirect all subdirectory pages to another?

Tags: htaccess, redirects

Due to duplicate content issue, I want to redirect all pages of `/articles/*` to newly created sub directory `/article/*`.

How do I redirect all pages of `/articles` to `/article` using `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this would resolve "duplicate content issues", but anyway...

```
Redirect 302 /articles/ /article/
```

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching, so the above matches `/articles/<anything>` and redirects to `/article/<anything>` - passing on the `<anything>` part.

This is naturally a 302 (temporary) redirect.

However, if you have other (particularly mod_rewrite) directives in your `.htaccess` then you may need to change this. The order is also important.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Comment: Thanks MrWhite, but the above answer isnt working. :(

Comment: Edit your question to show your *.htaccess* file.